# Error with sqlexp.ReturnMessage by nested query

Tags: sql, go, subquery, goroutine

I want to get message from RaisError by this code:

```
retmsg := &sqlexp.ReturnMessage{}
    rows, err = db.QueryContext(ctx, query, retmsg)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    active := true
    for active {
        msg := retmsg.Message(ctx)
        switch m := msg.(type) {
        case sqlexp.MsgNotice:
            result = fmt.Sprintf("%s", m.Message)
            return
        case sqlexp.MsgNext:
            inresult := true
            for inresult {
                inresult = rows.Next()
                if inresult {
                    var d interface{}
                    if err = rows.Scan(&d); err == nil {
                        result = fmt.Sprintf("%s %v", result, d)
                    }
                }
            }
        case sqlexp.MsgNextResultSet:
            active = rows.NextResultSet()
        case sqlexp.MsgError:
            result = fmt.Sprintf("%s", m.Error)
        }
    }
```

Procedure code that is used:

```
declare @err_message nvarchar(255), 
        @err_count int = 0
BEGIN
    if (isnull(@InStorageID,0)=0 and isnull(@OutStorageID,0)=0)  
     begin
       SET @err_message = ' Message: empty storage '
       select @err_count=@err_count+1
       RAISERROR (@err_message,10, 1) 
     end

     if (@Quantity<0 or @Quantity=0) 
     begin
       SET @err_message = ' Message: items quantity less than zero '
       select @err_count=@err_count+1
       RAISERROR (@err_message,10, 1) 
     end

     if not exists (select 1 from [dbo].[tblQuantity] qt
                where qt.ConsignmentID=@ConsignmentID and 
                      qt.StorageID=@OutStorageID and
                      (qt.Quantity-@Quantity)>=0
                 ) and @OutStorageID>0
     begin
       SET @err_message = ' Message: the quantity of goods is more than what is in stock '
       select @err_count=@err_count+1
       RAISERROR (@err_message,10, 1) 
     end

     if (@err_count=0)...
```

I can get messages "Message: empty storage" and "Message: items quantity less than zero". But "Message: the quantity of goods is more than what is in stock" cant.

Trouble start's at line:  msg := retmsg.Message(ctx)
it's runs block this block of package sqlexp, which hangs.

```
func (m *ReturnMessage) Message(ctx context.Context) RawMessage {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return MsgNextResultSet{}
    case raw := <-m.queue:
        return raw
    }
}
```

I try change context;

Change code into package sqlexp:
Adding default with emty message, but still not working.

I tried to debug in search of an error, but nothing worked, maybe the values are the same.

In my opinion this is due to a long wait for execution due to the execution of a subquery, but I'm not sure